# Form State is set to invalid - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using ngIf directive to add/remove field from DOM dynamically based on selection

But If I select AKG and then switch to Other option the form state becomes invalid

Here's my code-

```
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="college">College:</label>
              <label class="validations" @load *ngIf="!regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.college_name.valid && regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.college_name.touched">Please Select a College!</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="college" required placeholder="Select College" formControlName="college_name" (change)="makevalid(i)"> 
                <option value="akg">Ajay Kumar Garg Engineering College</option>
                <option value="other">Others- Please Specify Below</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.college_name.value === 'other'">
              <label for="cname">Enter College Name:</label>
              <label class="validations" @load *ngIf="!regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.college_name.valid && regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.college_name.touched">Please Enter a College Name!</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cname" required placeholder="Enter Your College Name"  formControlName="college_name_entry">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.college_name.value === 'akg'">
              <label for="studno">Student Number:</label>
              <label class="validations" @load style="font-size: 0.8em;" *ngIf="!regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.student_no.valid && regForm.controls.members.controls[i].controls.student_no.touched">Please Enter a Valid Student No.!</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studno" pattern="^([1][4-7]\d{5}[Dd]{0,1})$" required placeholder="Enter Your Student Number" formControlName="student_no">
            </div>
```

and in typescript-

```
makevalid(index) {
    console.log(index);
    if (this.regForm.value.members[index].college_name == 'other') {
        (<FormControl>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.regForm.controls.members).controls[index]).controls.student_no).updateValueAndValidity();    
    }
    else {
        (<FormControl>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.regForm.controls.members).controls[index]).controls.college_name_entry).updateValueAndValidity();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have not yet seen the TypeScript, but when you switch options, there will be no value in the "Enter College Name" input, correct? Because the `id="cname"` input is required, when it doesn't have a value, the whole form will be invalid, since that input does not pass its validation

Comment: But ngIf removes the input from DOM, not just hides it, So shouldnt it be valid again?

Comment: Both of the inputs have the potential to be invalid: `id="studno"` will be invalid when the value doesn't match its pattern, or when there's no value at all, because it has the `required` attribute. 

`id="cname"` will be invalid only when there's no value, because of the `required` attribute. As you explained the issue, it sounds like you're getting the invalid form state when you switch to displaying this field, correct? The `studno` input would indeed be removed from the DOM, but it's the required `cname` input that would be causing the invalid state, since it will be empty when added.

Comment: If you remove the `required` attribute from `cname`, I imagine the problem that you described will go away. If you need that field to be required when it exists, then the invalid form state would seem to be the expected behavior.

Comment: is there any method to explicitly assign form state as valid?

Comment: Not explicitly assign states of valid or invalid, because that would defeat the point of reactive forms, where you instead assign *validator functions* that *determine* validity. So in this case, after removing the `required` attribute, you initialize your FormControls, and do so with the `Validators.required` validator. Then in your `makeValid` function, you would use `someControl.setValidator()`, thus making your control have no validator, which would make it (and the form) always valid. If this fits your needs, I can write up a quick answer version